# Materialized View on pre-built table

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I am trying to find a way to build a materialized view with a table that is pre-populated with data .

The materialized view is created with "unknown" state. To support query rewriting, I called `dbms_mview.refresh`. However, I observed the pre-populated data are wiped out by the refreshing before the re-population.

Is there any way to preserve the data in the pre-built table without re-populating during MV refreshing?

Below is the code I've experimented with:

```sql
--simulate data population of the pre-built table
create table t_mv as select col1, col2, col3 from t order by col2;

--create the MV
create materialized view t_mv
on prebuilt table
enable query rewrite
as
    select col1, col2, col3 from t
;

--refresh the MV
exec dbms_mview.refresh(list => 'T_MV');

--## After MV refresh completed, data is not clustered by col2 as what it was in the pre-built table.
```

Comment: Can you share what you tried?  There is a “on prebuilt table” option.

Comment: @BobC - I edited my post with the script I used.

Answer (score 0):

A refresh just runs the query in the mview definition, so you'll need to include the ORDER BY in there as well, eg

```
SQL> create table t as select * from dba_objects;

Table created.

SQL> create table mv as select * from t order by object_type;

Table created.

SQL> create materialized view mv
  2  on prebuilt table
  3  enable query rewrite
  4  as select * from t order by object_type;

Materialized view created.
```

Also check out attribute clustering  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UndmvLZ4KSI

Comment: Thanks @Connor McDonald. I tried option you suggested. However, it doesn't bring the result expected.

After the "pre-built table" is created, I can see data is well clustered with `object_type`.

After the MV is created, it is with UNKNOWN STALENESS. Hence, I can't rely on it to rewrite query on table `t`. But after the MV is refreshed, data is not clustered with `object_type`.

I can achieve the result I expect by defining the "pre-built" table with attribute clustering. But since I created a MV on "pre-built" table, why does Oracle need to rebuild the content when the MV is refreshed?

Comment: prebuilt is about "i can build the MV *for the first time* without running the source SQL"...Subsequent refreshes will run the SQL.

Comment: Thanks. I got your point. But the difficulty I have is the "first time" built MV is not in a state that can be replied on for query writing. Hence the attempt for subsequent refreshing.